# Aiogram какие значение имеет джекпот и тп

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Меня интересует то какие значения имеют кости в телеграме. А именно ‘’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘⚽’ и ‘'.Нужно расписать по типу 1-2 попал 3-4

Answer (score 3):

Мы можем использовать [`send_dice`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/methods/send_dice.html) с необходимым нам параметром `emoji`, если обозначить его как объект сообщения, в нём будет располагаться `dice.value`, что хранит в себе значение игры. Разные игры при этом будут иметь разные значения. Значения в свою очередь нужно изучить и сопоставить.

Попробуйте следующий пример:

```
import random
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging import LoggingMiddleware
from aiogram.utils import executor

# Здесь замени 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' на свой API-ключ от @BotFather
API_TOKEN = 'токен'


# ‘’, ‘’, ‘’, ‘⚽’, ‘’, or ‘’
# Список с эмодзи

bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
logging_middleware = LoggingMiddleware()
dp.middleware.setup(logging_middleware)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['dice'])
async def roll_dice(message: types.Message):
    data = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'значение кубика {data.dice.value}')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['dart'])
async def roll_dice(message: types.Message):
    data = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'значение дартс {data.dice.value}')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['bask'])
async def roll_dice(message: types.Message):
    data = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'значение баскет {data.dice.value}')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['foot'])
async def roll_dice(message: types.Message):
    data = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='⚽')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'значение футбол {data.dice.value}')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['bowl'])
async def roll_dice(message: types.Message):
    data = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'значение боулинг {data.dice.value}')

@dp.message_handler(commands=['slot'])
async def roll_dice(message: types.Message):
    data = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'значение слоты {data.dice.value}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from aiogram import executor
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

---

Если вас интересуют значения в слотах, есть [следующий код на гитхабе](https://github.com/MasterGroosha/telegram-casino-bot/blob/aiogram3/bot/dice_check.py)

А именно имеется в виду следующая таблица для слотов

| Событие | Значения |
| --- | --- |
| Совпадающие значения (кроме 777) | 1, 22, 43 |
| Первые два значения - семерки | 16, 32, 48 |
| Все семерки | 64 |

---

Так из [этого же кода на гитхаб](https://github.com/MasterGroosha/telegram-casino-bot/blob/aiogram3/bot/dice_check.py) есть следующая реализация обозначения значений из слотов.

```
def get_combo_text(dice_value: int):
    """
    Возвращает то, что было на конкретном дайсе-казино
    :param dice_value: значение дайса (число)
    :return: массив строк, содержащий все выпавшие элементы в виде текста

    Альтернативный вариант (ещё раз спасибо t.me/svinerus):
        return [casino[(dice_value - 1) // i % 4]for i in (1, 4, 16)]
    """
    #           0       1         2        3
    values = ["BAR", "виноград", "лимон", "семь"]

    dice_value -= 1
    result = []
    for _ in range(3):
        result.append(values[dice_value % 4])
        dice_value //= 4
    return result
```

Используем данную реализацию и протестируем её

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['slot'])
async def roll_dice(message: types.Message):
    data = await bot.send_dice(message.chat.id, emoji='')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'значение слоты {get_combo_text(data.dice.value)}')
```

Результат работы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[Из документации Telegram API.](https://core.telegram.org/api/dice#:%7E:text=Slot%20machine,incremented%20by%20one.)

> Игровой автомат  dice stickers реализован несколько иначе: значение value не используется для непосредственного индексирования массива stickers, а используется следующим образом. Значение состоит из трех 2-битных значений, каждое из которых указывает на анимированный стикер, который нужно показать в трех слотах, с увеличением на единицу.